# When will it be considered an OVERKILL when making a composite primary key?

Tags: sql, database, primary-key, composite-primary-key

Recently, I stumbled upon this question when looking through my database notes.

In the case of an annual examination (A Levels, O Levels) where students who did not attain their desired marks are allowed for a re-sit in the following years,
suppose there was a database designed for the school to track that has the following attributes

```
Student ID, Exam module, Exam Date, Exam Results
```

**Question provided by the book (not my personal question)**: what would be some appropriate primary keys?[5]

Now, I know that several primary key should not be used:

1. Purely Student ID
2. (Student ID + Exam Module)

And I also know that perhaps

1. Artificial Primary Key - extending a 5th column that auto-increments
2. (Student ID + Exam Module + Exam Date)

could be used as a primary key

My **question** comes from making a composite primary key from all attributes (Student ID + Exam Module + Exam Date + Exam Results). A part of me thinks it will work as a composite primary key but it does not make sense to provide every single table with a composite primary key consisting of all columns.

Comment: Thanks for helping edit my grammar/sentence structure! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your description of the question, the following tuple of columns should be unique throughout the table: `(StudentID, ExamModule, ExamDate)`, because a student may take the same exam on different dates (actually: different years). The result of the exam should not be part of this unique column tuple: this prevents a student to two results for the same exam.

Whether you decide to make this tuple of columns the primary key of your table or use some kind of serial column as primary key is mostly a matter of taste. If you go for a serial key, you need to put a composite unique constraint on the three above columns anyway.

Comment: Thank you for that prompt response and answering my queries! Much appreciated :D

Answer (score 2):

This is not necessarily along the line of the OP's initial question:

> Question: what would be some appropriate primary keys?

but..(in hind site) I would have an IDENTITY field as a primary key.
And have the StudentID as just an Index (non unique) and as an alternate Key.

Comment: Thank you for your input :)) Means a lot!